# Building MongoDB C++ driver with MinGW and MSYS2

Tags: c++, windows, mongodb, mingw, msys

Trying to build MongoDB C++ driver for own project with MinGW from MSYS2.
I succefully builded `libbson` and `MongoDB C driver`. After that created build project for MinGW with the next command:

```
$ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=d:/build/mongo-cxx-driver -DLIBBSON_DIR=d:/build/mongo-c-driver -DLIBMONGOC_DIR=d:/build/mongo-c-driver -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1 ..
$ mingw32-make install
```

And after that build fails at 82%:

```
[ 82%] Building CXX object src/mongocxx/test/CMakeFiles/test_driver.dir/collection_mocked.cpp.obj
... (a lot of warnings)
D:/tools/mongo-cxx-driver/src/third_party/catch/include/catch.hpp:823:34: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
             return opCast( lhs ) ==  opCast( rhs );
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

mingw32-make[2]: *** [src\mongocxx\test\CMakeFiles\test_driver.dir\build.make:188: src/mongocxx/test/CMakeFiles/test_driver.dir/collection_mocked.cpp.obj] Error 1
```

The error occurs in third party software. How can I avoid this issue? Is it possible to not build tests for mongodb?

UPDATE:

The issue is solved by commenting `add_subdirectory(test)` line in `mongo-cxx-driver\src\bsoncxx\CMakeLists.txt` and in `mongo-cxx-driver\src\mongocxx\CMakeLists.txt`. This would remove requirements for testing and `catch` source will be ignored.